# Find $n$ such that the $10th$ term of the binomial expansion $(5+n)^n$ to be the greatest term.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

> Find $n$ such that the $10th$ term of the binomial expansion $(5+n)^n$ to be the greatest term.

I know that when $n$ is given i would take the ratio $\frac{T_{k+2}}{T_{k+1}}$ and compare it to 1 so i could find the greatest term. But now with n being an unkown i do not really get anything useful.

Then i tried using the ratio $\frac{T_{10}}{T_{k+1}}$ and compare it to 1 but again i did not know how to find $n$ from here.

What do you suggest ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MathJax hint:  To get multicharacter subscripts, enclose them in braces.  For example T_{k+2} gives $T_{k+2}$.  I believe this is what you meant in your post.  If you want to see how any MathJax was done, you can right click on it and Show Math As->Tex Commands. 
 You then want to compute $\frac {T_{11}}{T_{10}}$ and $\frac {T_9}{T_{10}}$.  Both should be less than $1$

Comment: I edited now. It should be ok

Comment: @RossMillikan why does computing  $\frac{T_{11}}{T_{10}}$ and $\frac{T_{9}}{T_{10}}$  and comparing to 1 work ? I mean why does it assure me that there can be no greater term ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: The binomial terms start from a minimum, reach a maximum, and decrease.  Here the first term is $5^n$, the middle ones are larger, and the last is $n^n$.  We are just looking for the one that is larger than its neighbors.

Comment: @RossMillikan oh so it's similar to $(1+1)^n$ for example because here it is clear that the middle term will be the greatest as we have only values of combinations. Does every binomial expansion exhibit the same behavior(increase-reach maximum-decrease)?

Comment: It can be a maximum at one end, but otherwise yes.

Comment: @RossMillikan ok then. Thanks !